# Query LDAP for a userCertificate attribute using python-ldap

Tags: python, ldap, python-ldap

I am trying to query a "userCertificate;binary" attribute using python-ldap library. The purpose is to authenticate a user using his own certificate. My code look like this :

```
# Search parameters
searchScope = ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE
searchFilter = "userCertificate;binary="+str(certificate)
retrieveAttributes = None

#Searching LDAP entry
result  = con.search_s(ldap_base,searchScope,searchFilter,retrieveAttributes)
```

This returns "bad search filter" exception from ldap.

**Questions** :
How can such a query be formulated ?

Thank you.

**Edit** : I found a workaround for this problem but the problem still persists, i will do more research for the actual issue.

Comment: Does [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/431944/problems-with-ldap-usercertificate-attribute) help ? You may have to escape `str(certificate)` after ensuring that the filters value corresponds to what is described in https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4523#section-2.5

Comment: I will try that but i dont really know what should be exactly escaped given that my certificate format is non utf-8,  I still found a way around this problem.

Comment: You can *accept* your answer then if it solved the problem, given your actual question, if not (just a workaround) then you can edit your post to ask for further research on the actual issue. The workaround you provided is useful (+1) but may not clear the issue as it is asked. As a new user, know that this is important to take into account for others that could encounter the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to bypass the problem by searching for the entry "cn" attribute unstead of the certificate then converting the retrieved DER certificate to a PEM format and comparing it to the request PEM certificate, this way there wont be any problem with non utf-8 DER encoding. My code looks like this.

```
# Reading certification request
crt_request = request.form["certificate"]
crt_request = str.encode(crt_request)
# Search parameters
cn = request.form["cn"]
searchScope = ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE
searchFilter = "cn=*"+cn+"*"
retrieveAttributes = None

#Searching LDAP entry
result  = con.search_s(ldap_base,searchScope,searchFilter,retrieveAttributes)
if( not result) :
    return jsonify("Entry not found"),401
#Getting DER certificate and converting it to PEM
der_cert = result[0][1]
der_cert = der_cert.get("userCertificate;binary")[0]
try : 
    certificate = x509.load_der_x509_certificate(der_cert,default_backend())
    crt = certificate.public_bytes(serialization.Encoding.PEM)
except ldap.LDAPError:
    return jsonify("Bad certification format"),401
if(crt == crt_request ) :
    return jsonify(crt),200
else :
    return jsonify("Unvalid certificate"),401
```